# What are you if you specialize in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

If you specialize in number theory or in computer science (this for cryptology) you are a number theorist, a computer scientist, a cryptologist.

But how do you call someone who specializes in combinatorics?

I've tried to google *combinatorician* and *combinatorist* but the number one search engine does not know about these substantives and thinks they are just misspellings.

Comment: Try *combinatorialist* and see if it improves your results.

Comment: I second "combinatorialist," though I've also had graph theorists refer to themselves as "combinatorists."

Comment: "combinatoricist" gets some hits.

Comment: Combinatorialist works (at least for Google). 1.0E06 thanks! Are there some combinatorialists who don't like being called that?

Comment: I (and others) use *combinatorist*; I have also encountered *combinatorialist*.

Comment: Is someone who specialises in analysis called an analyst?

Comment: @HBeel Yes, in fact.

Answer (score 3):

Search engines these days know a lot. It certainly scares me when I search for "flag manifold" and receive results for "flag variety." However, they don't know everything.

If you look at the Wikipedia article for combinatorics, it tells you that the terms that are in use are combinatorialist and combinatorist. These are also the only terms I myself have heard used for those who study combinatorics.